# Finding different Proteins with same function

Tags: phylogenetics

Could you help me about finding two different proteins that coming from different ancestors, perform same function?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There will be a lot!  Chromosomal dihydrofolate reductase and type II (plasmid) dihydrofolate reductase have not been derived from common  ancestor but catalyze completely the same reaction including stereochemistry by the authority of [Brito](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bi00494a011?journalCode=bichaw).

Bacterial phenylalanine hydroxylase too is completely different in sequence of amino acids from phenylalanine hydroxylase from mammals (where plants have no such protin). The literature shows this paper [Cloning and nucleotide sequencing of phenylalanine dehydrogenase gene of Bacillus sphaericus](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0378111988905379).